Problems pulling nested JSON data from a REST API using Python
Newbie here. I am working on a Python script to pull data from a REST API. I am trying to pull data from a list of people. I can get data such as the user's first_name, last_name, id, etc. When I try to pull the contact_primary_email I get an error message stating "An error occurred: 'contact_primary_email'". I am not sure why I am getting this error message. I have tried to use the following code to pull the email address. Below is the sample response from the API along with the code snippet. Any ideas on how I can fix this?
Thank you in advance!
SAMPLE RESPONSE
{
    "object": "list",
    "count": 200,
    "results": 2558,
    "results_per_page": 200,
    "pages": 13,
    "page": 1,
    "offset": 0,
    "has_more": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "object": "person",
            "id": 194339,
            "first_name": "David",
            "last_name": "Ross",
            "middle_name": "Mike",
            "prefix": null,
            "suffix": null,
            "preferred_name": null,
            "display_name": "David Ross",
            "gender": "male",
            "other_gender": null,
            "raceid": 0,
            "image_file_id": 146197,
            "birth_date": "2000-10-26",
            "status": "active",
            "alien_registration_number": null,
            "home_city": "Chicago",
            "home_state": "IL",
            "home_country": "US",
            "former_name": null,
            "license_plate": null,
            "bio": null,
            "updated_at": "2024-04-02T16:46:15+00:00",
            "hispanic_latino": false,
            "resident_alien": false,
            "localization_id": null,
            "notification_email_id": null,
            "deceased_date": null,
            "added_by_id": 154,
            "added_at": "2024-04-02T15:13:14+00:00",
            "import_id": 649,
            "report_data": {
                "person_id": 194339,
                "active_roles": "5",
                "username": "david.ross",
                "primary_address_street": "199511 Emerald Shores Drive #109374",
                "primary_address_city": "Chicago",
                "primary_address_state": "IL",
                "primary_address_country": "US",
                "is_alum": 0,
                "primary_org_title": null,
                "primary_org_name": null,
                "contact_primary_email": "David.Ross@my.fakemail.com",
                "contact_primary_phone": "(123) 322-3222",
                "visible_student_id": "1241269"
            },
            "private_profile": false,
            "is_user": true
        },
        {
            "object": "person",
            "id": 194133,
            "first_name": "Kathy",
            "last_name": "Horten",
            "middle_name": "",
            "prefix": null,
            "suffix": null,
            "preferred_name": null,
            "display_name": "Kathy Horten",
            "gender": null,
            "other_gender": null,
            "raceid": 0,
            "image_file_id": null,
            "birth_date": null,
            "status": "active",
            "alien_registration_number": null,
            "home_city": null,
            "home_state": null,
            "home_country": null,
            "former_name": null,
            "license_plate": null,
            "bio": null,
            "updated_at": "2024-04-02T14:00:33+00:00",
            "hispanic_latino": false,
            "resident_alien": false,
            "localization_id": null,
            "notification_email_id": null,
            "deceased_date": null,
            "added_by_id": 38,
            "added_at": "2024-04-02T14:00:32+00:00",
            "import_id": null,
            "report_data": {
                "person_id": 194133,
                "active_roles": "4",
                "username": null,
                "primary_address_street": null,
                "primary_address_city": null,
                "primary_address_state": null,
                "primary_address_country": null,
                "is_alum": 0,
                "primary_org_title": null,
                "primary_org_name": null,
                "contact_primary_email": "kathy.horten@fakegmail.com",
                "contact_primary_phone": "(123) 333-2222",
                "visible_student_id": null
            },
            "private_profile": false,
            "is_user": false
        },
    ],
    "sandbox": false
}

CODE SNIPPET
import requests
import json
import csv

# Define the base URI and API endpoint
base_uri = "https://host.fakewebweb.com"
api_endpoint = "/api/people"

# Define the API key and set it as a header for authentication
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer sk_goes_here"
}

# Define the file name with the current date and time
from datetime import datetime
file_name_csv = "people-data_"+datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")+".txt"

def fetch_people_data():
    """
    Fetch people data from the specified API endpoint and save the data to a CSV file and a JSON file.
    """
    try:
        # Make the initial API request to get the total pages
        response = requests.get(base_uri + api_endpoint, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        total_pages = data["pages"]

        # Create a CSV file and write the header row
        print("STATUS: Create CSV file to receive data.")
        with open(file_name_csv, "w", newline="") as csv_file:
            csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, dialect='piper')
            csv_writer.writerow(["EXTERNAL_PERSON_KEY", "USER_ID", "SYSTEM_ROLE", "FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "EMAIL", "INSTITUTION_ROLE"])

            print("STATUS: Writing header of CSV file.")
            print("STATUS: Writing data to CSV file...this may take a minute or two.")

            # Initialize an empty list to store people data for JSON output
            people_data = []

            # Loop through all the pages and collect data
            for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
                # Define the request body with the page parameter
                body = {
                    "page": page
                }
                response = requests.get(base_uri + api_endpoint, headers=headers, json=body)

                data = response.json()

                # Iterate through the people data and write rows to the CSV file, and store data in the list
                for person in data["data"]:
                    populi_uid = person["id"]
                    user_id = person["contact_primary_email"]
                    firstname = person["first_name"]
                    lastname = person["last_name"]
                    email = person["contact_primary_email"]
                    external_person_key = person["id"]

                    csv_writer.writerow([external_person_key user_id, "none", firstname, lastname, email, "student"])

                    # Add person data to the list for JSON output
                    people_data.append({
                        "id": external_person_key,
                        "first_name": firstname,
                        "last_name": lastname,
                        "email": email
                    })

            print("STATUS: Completed creating list for JSON file.")  

        # Save the people data as a JSON file
        print("STATUS: Writing JSON file...")
        with open(file_name_json, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(people_data, json_file, indent=4)

        print("STATUS: Data successfully fetched and saved to: "+file_name_csv+" and "+file_name_json)

Here is the error message:
An error occurred: 'contact_primary_email'

I've searched for solutions but am not finding a solution (at least not one I'm understanding). Thanks!

what is the type of error exactly? Also the sample response you provided cannot be formatted as json, can you check it pls?

It's hard to say for sure because you have not given all the details, but at a guess I'd say it's because some person objects don't have a contact_primary_email field.

You need to use dictionary.get("contact_primary_email") instead of using index access.

Does this answer your question? Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?

@user70  Thank you for your reply! Forgive me for asking this newbie question, but does the python dictionary.get("contact_primary_email") replace the python user_id = person["contact_primary_email"] and the python email = person["contact_primary_email"] lines in the script?

Using user_id = person.get("contact_primary_email") instead of user_id = person["contact_primary_email"] allows the code to fall back on a default value for that key if it is not found.

The answer you provide as example simply isn't JSON, something's broken there, either in the code or your question.

@UlrichEckhardt  Thanks for the feedback! I've updated the JSON response to better reflect the output from the API. There are a large number of records, so I've edited it down to two records that should be representative of the overall data. Hopefully this helps.

You are looking in the wrong location for the contact_primary_email key.  It is not at the same level as the id key, it is is a sub-dictionary.

@JohnGordon So does this mean I need a different path?

Yes, you need person["report_data"]["contact_primary_email"]
